# CSS (WordPress) different image position for different browsers

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have an image link with a transition to another image and in Chrome, Edge, IE11 all are displaying properly. But in Firefox one single image is misplaced by a few px. You can view the page at http://444.a91.myftpupload.com/. I use element inspector on Chrome and Firefox and CSS is same but for the life of me I have not been able to fix this.

HTML image that is in wrong position:

```
<span id="zone-c"><a href="http://444.a91.myftpupload.com/projects/">
<img class="bottom" src="http://444.a91.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/see-the-work-center-hover.png" alt="" width="482" height="136"></a>
<a href="http://444.a91.myftpupload.com/projects/">
<img class="top" src="http://444.a91.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/see-the-work-center.png" alt="" width="482" height="136"></a>
</span>
```

CSS that is messing with me:

```
.top, .bottom {
  left: -15px;
  top: 16px;
}
```

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be aligning layouts manually with `position:absolute` and position values. You should try something like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), or use `float: left` and sizes to position the elements properly on their own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @casraf.
It looks like you are using Visual Composer.

Anyway, I think

```
.top, .bottom {
  left: -15px;
  margin-top: 16px;
}
```

would fix your problem.

Comment: You are correct @Murshid Ahmed I am using visual composer. And thanks for the fix of margin-top. I can't believe I did not think of that but it works perfectly now!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please select as answer if you are happy :)